# Output a list of all file names in a directory with the last 5 characters removed from each

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a directory that contains files with names,

```
00004.time, 00010.time, ...
```

There is not pattern except the format,

```
<5 decimal digits>.time
```

I would like to output to a file, just the numbers in ascending order.  How can I do this from the command line or with script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bash shell, you can remove a 'dot extension' (shortest trailing pattern matching a period followed by any number of characters) from a variable that contains a file name using *parameter expansion* e.g. if  `f=00004.time` then `${f%.*}` evaluates to `00004`.

Putting that in a loop over a shell glob,

```
for f in *.time; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}"; done
```

The order will be determined by the glob (`*.time`) expansion, and will be the default collation order for your locale - which should be numeric ascending for the input you show. To send the results to a file, use shell redirection

```
for f in *.time; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}"; done > somefile
```

If you *really* want to remove the last 5 characters instead of the (more general) dot extension, you can modify that to

```
for f in *.time; do printf '%s\n' "${f%?????}"; done > somefile
```

Comment: Don't embed variables into printf's format string. If it happens to contain any `%` or ``\`` characters, it will fail or give unintended output. Use `printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}"` instead of `printf "${f%.*}\n"`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617107/216503), as the substring to be excluded is same for all files, you can use substitution operation of the `bash`'s parameter expansion:

```
for file in *.time; do echo "${file/.time/}"; done | sort -n > file.txt
```

This will replace `.time` with empty string i.e. `.time` is excluded from the file names.

The syntax for substitution operation is

```
${Parameter/OLD/NEW}
```

This will substitute only the first occurrence of `OLD` with `NEW`, if you want all occurrence of `OLD` to be replaced with `NEW`:

```
${Parameter//OLD/NEW}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just want numbers, and do not want `.time` part. My two cents here:

```
ls /path/to/*.time | cut -d '.' -f1  > toSomeFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the same by combination of [find](/questions/tagged/find) and `basename` commands as follows:

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.time' -exec basename {} .time \; > someFile
```

The `basename {} .time`, strips the ".time" suffix from fileNames.
The `{}` represent the current found fileName.